# Detox iOS dynamic link is null for `firebase.dynamicLinks().getInitialLink()`

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, detox

I'm using Firebase Dynamic links as a Deep Link handler. And on iOS `firebase.dynamicLinks().getInitialLink()` constantly returns `null`.

Code is simple:

```
await device.launchApp({
  newInstance: true,
  sourceApp: APP_ID,
  url: EMAIL_VERIFY_LINK
});
```

Detox: `17.10.6`, RN: `0.63.2`

@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links: `7.3.5`, @react-native-firebase/app: `8.4.2`

Comment: @LeoNatan any ideas?

Comment: I’m not sure, not familiar with Firebase. Please put a breakpoint in the app delegate and see if the parameters are sent correctly on launch.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing it as well.

Comment: @HK808 we removed e2e tests for deep links for now, so not sure :)